# Write a query to show the assessment code, name and no of version which have more than 1 versions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, one having the assessment code and assessment name.
The other table assessment version is linked to the former table by same assessment code but it is having different versions of assessments.

The answer till found is:

```
select distinct a.name, a.code, av.ver_no
from assessments a, assessment_vers av
where a.code = av.ass_code
  and av.ver_no > 1
order by a.code
```

The assessment code with all the versions greater than 1 is coming whereas I just want the last or max version of each assessment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a `group by`:

```
select a.name, a.code, max(av.ver_no) ver_no_max
from assessments a, assessment_vers av
where a.code = av.ass_code
group by a.name, a.code
having max(av.ver_no) > 1
order by a.code
```